# DataGrid won't show data of the next page

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, pagination, paging

my DataGrid shows data from the first page no matter what page i clicked, i have searched for solution but nothing works. i have put `BindGrid` on `!IsPostBack` and rebind the grid on `grid1_PageIndexChanging`. here is my codes:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGrid();
    }
}

private int GetNumItems()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = gc.GetWebConfigConnectionStringAIS();
    con.Open();
    string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.TestingLatihan";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    Int32 totalRow = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    con.Close();

    return totalRow;
}

protected void grid1_PageIndexChanging(object source, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridPageChangedEventArgs e)
{
    grid1.CurrentPageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    BindGrid();
}

private void BindGrid() 
{
    grid1.VirtualItemCount = GetNumItems();
    grid1.PageIndexChanged += new DataGridPageChangedEventHandler(grid1_PageIndexChanging);

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = gc.GetWebConfigConnectionStringAIS();
    con.Open();
    string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.TestingLatihan";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

    SqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    myAdapter.Fill(dt);

    grid1.DataSource = dt;
    grid1.DataBind();

    con.Close();  
}
```

and my .aspx

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="grid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" Width="100%" 
OnItemCommand="dtgItemCommand" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5" 
AllowCustomPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanged="grid1_PageIndexChanging" 
EnableViewState="true">
   <AlternatingItemStyle CssClass="tdgenap" />
   <ItemStyle CssClass="tdganjil" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
      <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Height="30px" CssClass="tdjudul"></HeaderStyle>
          <Columns>
             <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="ID" >
                <HeaderStyle Font-Underline="false" Height="15px" Width="5%" HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#ccffcc"></HeaderStyle>
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label id="lblID" runat="server" text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID_")%>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateColumn>
            <PagerStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="black" HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="True" Mode="NumericPages" />
             <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
</asp:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@vin, here it seems like you enable both property  AllowPaging="True"  & AllowCustomPaging="True". As default code for it is AllowPaging="True" then i try with that see my below example. Might be it help you to sort out your issue.

your aspx.cs code should be similar as

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindGrid();
        }
    }
    protected void grid1_PageIndexChanging(object source, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridPageChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        grid1.CurrentPageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        BindGrid();
    }

    private int GetNumItems()
    {
        int totalRow = 15;
        return totalRow;
    }
    private void BindGrid()
    {

        grid1.DataSource = GetTable();
        grid1.DataBind();
    }
    public DataTable GetTable()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        table.Rows.Add(1, "David");
        table.Rows.Add(2, "Sam");
        table.Rows.Add(3, "Christoff");
        table.Rows.Add(4, "Janet");
        table.Rows.Add(5, "Melanie");
        table.Rows.Add(6, "David1");
        table.Rows.Add(7, "Sam1");
        table.Rows.Add(8, "Christoff1");
        table.Rows.Add(9, "Jane1t");
        table.Rows.Add(10, "Melanie1");
        return table;
    }
```

your .aspx code code should be similar as

```
        <asp:DataGrid ID="grid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" Width="100%"
           AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5" 
            OnPageIndexChanged="grid1_PageIndexChanging"
            >
            <AlternatingItemStyle CssClass="tdgenap" />
            <ItemStyle CssClass="tdganjil" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Height="30px" CssClass="tdjudul"></HeaderStyle>
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="ID">
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Underline="false" Height="15px" Width="5%" HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#ccffcc"></HeaderStyle>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
            </Columns>
            <PagerStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="black" HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="True" Mode="NumericPages" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        </asp:DataGrid>
```

Let me know is that solution works for your or not?